# Firebase: Firestore Query for Longest Match

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My document looks like:

```
ABC: 1
ABCD: 2
ABCDE: 3
ABCDEF: 4
```

I want to query for longest match, in other words, `myVar = ABCDEFGHIJ` and I want the field with value `4` (the longest match).

Here's a use case - finding the discount to apply to a part number/stock keeping unit (sku). Say you have a family of products with a blanket 10% discount, however, a series of products in this family has a promo discount of 20%, e.g. FORD-ESCAPE, FORD-MUSTANG, FORD-ANYTHING has a 10% discount but trucks such as FORD-F150, FORD-F250, and FORD-F350 have a discount of 20%.

So, the "discount" document looks like:

```
"FORD-": 0.1
"FORD-F" : 0.2
```

My variable is `"FORD-F250"`. How to query for the longest match, which tells me the discount to apply?

Comment: I don't understand the use case here.  Are you saying you already have a document in hand and you want to find its longest field name?  Or are you trying to find the document with the longest field name?  In either case, I don't think there's a query that can help you.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I updated question to clarify.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to query like this.

Comment: Agreed with Doug. This seems beyond the query capabilities of Firestore, unless @DanMcGrath has a trick up his sleeve that neither of us can think of.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just FYI: I was able to script a cloud function to do the longest match query server side which met my requirement/desire to not publish (send) the entire discounting schedule to the public/clients. So, I got a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Based on feedback, it sounds like a longest match query isn't currently supported in Firestore. However, I was able to create my own with a custom cloud function then [Call functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). The Node.js JavaScript below works for me:

```
exports.getDiscount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var item = data.item;
    var make = data.make;
    var baseDiscount = 0;
    var baseDiscountId = "";
    var discount = 0;
    var discountMatchDepth = 0;
    if (make === "ford"){
        baseDiscountId = "ford-base-discount";
    }
    if (make === "chevy"){
        baseDiscountId = "chevy-base-discount";
    }    
    //fetchDiscounts() simply pushes each sku-prefix/discount to array of arrays
    return fetchDiscounts().then(function(discounts) {
        //calculate discount
        for (var i = 0; i < discounts.length; i++) {
            if (discounts[i][0] === baseDiscountId) {
                baseDiscount = discounts[i][1];
            }
            if (item.startsWith(discounts[i][0])) {
                if (discounts[i][0].length > discountMatchDepth) {
                    discountMatchDepth = discounts[i][0].length;
                }
                discount = discounts[i][1];
            }
        }
        if(discount === 0) {
            discount = baseDiscount;
        } 
        return {discount: discount};
    });
});
```